# How can I repair exchange public folder database?

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

I have an Exchange 2007 box, that in order to update to SP2/SP3, in preparation for 2010, I had to manually remove the old Exchange 2003 active directory left overs. In doing so I suspect I broke the ability for the Public folders database to load correctly.

Now Exchange tells me:

Exchange is unable to mount the database that you specified. Specified database: POWERHOG\Public Folders\Public Folder Database; Error code: MapiExceptionCallFailed: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=-550)

Now, I still have the .edb file, and nothing has changed in that file itself as far as I am aware. How can I get Exchange to load this file, or recover the data into a new public folder if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the article Chris posted doesn't help, you may find the eseutil useful - it can be used to recover/check the state of a database:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/149029-resolve-error-unable-to-mount-database-hr-0x80004005-ec-550

Comment: 0x80004005 isn't a corrupted DB error, so I don't think eseutil will fix it. It might be worth a try however. Be sure to take a backup copy of the files before running this.

Answer (score 1):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925825/en-us